# Автоматическое открытие порта

Tags: delphi, tcp-ip

Можно ли через дельфи, открыть нужный порт по протоколу TCP автоматически? Если да, то наглядно объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Всмысле прослушивать определенный порт или программно открыть его на файрволе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

прослушивать - TSocketServer. если нормальный файрвол то программно открыть не должно быть возможности

Comment: Я подозреваю, брандмауэром windows можно порулить программно. )

Comment: если бранджауэром рулить програмно то ето не брандмауэр а фигня какаято. представь троян берет повышает привелегии до админа и програмно через апи прописывает себя в довереные приложения .....